# React Reducer fails to recognize action.type comparison

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, reducers

Since this is rather difficult to explain, the whole source code is available at Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/5z9m4lj1ln

**Problem:** An `action` is properly dispatched but the `reducer` is not reacting to it. I have also attached another `action`, and it is working perfectly. oddly enough, `if` condition is not working only for certain `actions`, while the other `action` is performing alright. I've even double checked if I misspelled the `type` of `action`, but it doesn't seem to be a typo. It just seems the comparison for the `action.type` is failing for certain case and I don't know why.

below is the simplified code. in case you cannot spot the problem, I also marked the spot with `// ***this is not reachable!` comment in the codesandbox above.

Reducer

```
// reducer
reducerA(state, action) => {
  console.log('reducer is working'); // somehow this console message works!
  console.log(action) // and I've checked the action from here;
  // it appears to be an object with proper type, payload
  console.log('DELETED, action.type) // it seems to be the exactly same stuff!
  if (action.type === 'DELETED') {
    console.log('deleted'); // ***this is not reachable!
    return { ...someState };
  }
  return defaultValue;
}

export default combineReducers({
  reducerA,
  reducerB // some other reducer
})
```

Action Creator

```
export const deleteOp = title => {
  return {
    type: "DELETED",
    payload: title
  };
};
```

actual component with the problem

```
const myComponent = ({ dataA, deleteOp }) => {
  return <button onClick={() => deleteOp(dataA.title)}>delete</button>
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ dataA: state.reducerA }); // this works fine
// data seems to be distributed properly
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { deleteOp })(myComponent);
```

Could you point out if I miss something?

Comment: I dont know how anything is working, you never call dispatch() in your action ?

Comment: I am following a video instruction course about react/redux; the instructor said I don't need to because I am using `{ connect } from 'react-redux`. so I did the exact same thing and some actions really worked. I've also omitted presumable `import` part from the code for simplification. Full working code is available at codesandbox(https://codesandbox.io/s/5z9m4lj1ln)

Comment: Check console. You have errors in your actual code.`state.songs.filter` should be `state.filter`. Also you have incorrect implemented reducer. It would return a new array for any action it  can't recognize. By default it should return state untouched.

Comment: Thank you @YuryTarabanko ! now I just know it; somehow any errors happened in the reducer are hidden from the console and these hinder other reducer actions as well.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/vy9l8273y5 working example when errors been fixed.

Comment: Thank you for the insight! it really helped!

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help ;)